# Отображение ошибки в phpStorm

Tags: php

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста не пойму почему phpStorm подсвечивает код switch как ошибку
может что то пропустил
[image: скрин ошибки]

Comment: Минус за некачественное оформление вопроса: код надо вставлять текстом, а не прикреплять картинкой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что после return код выполняться не будет.

Comment: спасибо большое а если я заменю return на echo?

Comment: @АкопянЕвгений just do it